# PHP show names of all declared classes?

Tags: php, class, instance-variables

Lets say I have this code:

```
<?php
class hello {
    var $greeting = "hello";
    function hello(){
        echo $this->greeting;
        return;
    }
}

$hello1 = new hello;
$hello2 = new hello;
$hello4 = new hello;
?>
```

How do I get it to echo all the names of instantiated objects (and if possible their respective class), so that it echos (possibly in an array) "hello1 => hello, hello2 => hello, hello4 => hello".

If this is not possible, is there any way to tell the name of the instance from within the class, something like echo instance_name($this); would get me "hello1". Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't want to edit the title but it's a bit misleading. There's only one class declared, class hello. You're looking for _instances_ of this (or any other) class and variables that reference those instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could call `get_defined_vars` to get an array of all the objects present, and then use `get_class` to get the class names for each one (code not tested, but it should work):

```
$vars = array();
foreach (get_defined_vars() as $var) {
    $vars[$var] = get_class($var);
}
```

FYI, what you call a "declared class" is more well known as an "object."

Your second question is not possible. Take, for example:

```
$hello1 = $hello2 = new hello();
```

Now, if I call `instance_name`, should it return 'hello1' or 'hello2'?

Comment: True.. and combine with is_object if necessary to find which vars are objects

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was looking into get_defined_vars(), but I didn't know that objects are also in there, I'll thank a look again, thanks.